# How to reinstall windows 10 on a partitionned disk properly and avoid duplicating recovery partitions?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, reinstall, partition-recovery

My pc recently crashed and I had to reinstall w10. But now when I'm booting on the disk, I get 2 windows installed

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLiFO.jpg)

Here is how I did :

My disk is originally partitioned in 2 :

- C : for the OS
- D : for the rest (softwares, games, …)

I used a bootable usb key to install w10 and when I had to choose the space where to install:

- I selected the C (OS)
- did « format »
- then « next »

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fT2mg.png)

Installation was successful and deleted the old windows except that when booting on the disk I get these 2 windows:

- « Windows 10 on volume 4 » which is the new working install
- « Windows 10 » the other residual one

When looking at Disk Management I get 2 recovery partitions, the one from the new install and the one from the old install. I guess that is the latter one which is causing this issue when booting (?)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs9jd.png)

I probably did a bad install of w10.

So my question is:

Should I reinstall windows but when it comes to the choice of the space where to install it, I delete all the partitions (Recovery, system, MSR, C and D) and I reinstall on the only unallocated space remaining so it could be a cleaner installation ?

Sorry for this long message, hope it is clear. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have two installations of Windows, just two boot entries.

It's easy enough to get rid of a spurious boot entry :

- Run `msconfig`
- Position to the Boot tab
- Click the spurious boot entry
- Click Delete.

Be careful to delete the right boot entry.
Reboot to ensure that no harm was done.

This would leave you with an extra "Partition de récupération",
taking up around 500 MB, which is too small to worry about.

Comment: OK thank you for your answer, it did work ! Concerning the recovery partition, can I still remove it ? Or is it not advised ?

Comment: You have two of them, so better not take the chance of deleting the wrong one. As it's very small, it's not worth the risk. It also happens naturally when upgrading Windows to a new version. Some people have more than two.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advices !